# simple-html-dom loop not ending

Tags: php, loops, hyperlink, simple-html-dom

I am trying to cature all the links and then go to the next page until the end of the pages.
I just keep getting a loop.  I think I am just glazed over and was hoping that once again I can get some help today.

getLinks('http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZaqns/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&storeId=10051&catStyle=ShowProducts#/?c=1&style=List');

```
   function getLinks($URL) {


$html = file_get_contents($URL);

$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$dom -> load($html);

    foreach ($dom->find('a[class=item_description]') as $href){
  $url = $href->href;
  echo $url;
 }



if ($nextPage = $dom->find("a[class='paginationNumberStyle page_arrows']", 0)){ 

    $nextPageURL = 'http://www.homedepot.com'.$nextPage->getAttribute('data-url'); 

    $dom -> clear();
    unset($dom);
    getLinks($nextPageURL);
} else {
    echo "\nEND";
    $dom -> clear();
    unset($dom);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please fix your indentation? Also, the `getLinks` function appears to be unclosed.

Comment: What happens if page A links to page B, but then page B links back to page A? I think you need to keep a list of pages you've visited.

Comment: page a links to pageb?  This should just collects the links and then go to the next page and collect the rest to the end.  Am I completely screwed up?  I am not use to simplehtmldom and a friend really wants to use it.

Comment: I'll post as an answer.

Comment: You are right this line   ($nextPage = $dom->find("a[class='paginationNumberStyle page_arrows']",   could link forward or back.  Does anyone know how to specify the last occurance of ($nextPage = $dom->find("a[class='paginationNumberStyle page_arrows']", ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you never keep track of where you've been.

Let's say you start on page A:

- The first link on page A links to page B.
- You open up page B and start crawling the links.
- The first link on page B links to page A.
- You open up page A and start crawling the links ....

This process will repeat indefinitely, because you'll end up crawling the same pages over and over. You need to keep a list of pages you've crawled and skip out if you've already crawled that page.

Also note that it may not be a simple loop like that.

- A links to B
- B links to C
- C links to D
- ....
- S links to T
- T links to A

Not overly familiar with PHP, but something like:

```
$arr[$url] = true; // Tell it that we know the url
if (array_key_exists($url, $arr)) { 
    // check if the url exists in the hash
}
```

Comment: Don't do it this way, this overcomplicates the problem.

Comment: I am going nutty right now and thinking I don't remember anything at this point.

Comment: Could I possibly point to this area <a class="paginationNumberStyle page_arrows" data-url="/Building-Materials/h_d1/N-5yc1vZaqns/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&amp;Nu=P_PARENT_ID&amp;langId=-1&amp;Nao=192&amp;storeId=10051"> 
                        <img alt="" src="/static/images/layout/triangle-green-right.gif"></a>   which is the next arrow page?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're following previous arrows as well as next arrows. Your css selector needs to be adjusted to account for this.